# Material UI override react subtree except for certain components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to override the theme of a react sub-tree, but skip the override for certain components?

I'm overriding all children of a component, making sure all the font size is small, using:

```
const overrideTheme = (theme: Theme): Theme => {
   return createTheme({
     ...theme,
     typography: {
       fontSize: 11,
     }
   })
}

const MyCustomThemeWrapper = ({children}) => {
   return (
      <div>
         <ThemeProvider theme={overrideTheme}>
            {children}
         </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
   )
}
```

What I want to do is make this override exclude certain components (and their children). In particular, I don't want to override the font size of any `Dialog` components that's part of the `children` subtree. Any way I can do this, without having to "re-override" the theme for each `Dialog`? I.e. I want something this:

```
const Component1 = () => {
   return (
       <MyCustomThemeWrapper>
           <div>
              This text has fontSize 11
              <span> more font size 11</span>
              <Dialog open={open}>
                <DialogContent>
                   This text has the "original" fontSize
                </DialogContent>
              </Dialog>
           </div>
       </MyCustomThemeWrapper>
    )
```

}

where the custom theme override "hits" all the children of `MyCustomThemeWrapper` except for the `Dialog` subtree. I know I'm asking for much here, but would be really nice if this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can override inline component's styles with wrapping another `ThemeProvider` as a parent to inline components. For instance, If you would like to except the `Dialog` component from override `ThemeProvider`, You should wrap it with another `ThemeProvider`. Because of your code wasn't clear enough to describing on it, I've made another example which in that inline `checkbox`s styles, override by another  `ThemeProvider`:

```
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import { green, orange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const outerTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: orange[500]
    }
  }
});

const innerTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    secondary: {
      main: green[500]
    }
  }
});

const CustomCheckBox = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={innerTheme}>
      <Checkbox defaultChecked />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={outerTheme}>
      <Checkbox defaultChecked />
      <Checkbox defaultChecked />
      <CustomCheckBox />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Here's the result:

[image: Result]

[image: Edit adoring-surf-gsykv]

Comment: I know this is possible, and it's kinda what I'm trying to avoid. What I'm asking for is ways of setting the theme for an entire component subtree, but skip overriding the theme of certain MUI components, like Dialog in my example above. Again, I might be asking for much here, and I'm left with having to add a ThemeProvider for each Dialog in the subtree, but would be really interesting to see if there was a way around this.

Comment: @simen-andresen Excuse me, I've understood incorrectly. In this situation which you described, you can create a another `Dialog` component which has its own `ThemeProvider` and use that `Dialg` component instead of original component in another components. I updated the code for better understanding.